# Querying nearest item

Tags: boto, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table which has timestamp as `range_key`. My aim is to retrieve the item which has nearest date to a given timestamp. When I query like that `t.query(hash_key="somename", range_key_condition = db.boto.dynamodb.condition.LT(1389799297))` it gets all items less than given timestamp naturally and I take nearest one. I can also achieve this by using `BETWEEN` comparator by substructing some constant seconds from current time and query between these timestamps and select the last one which is nearest to the original timestamp. If it returns no result than I decrement a bit more and retry until I have a non-empty result set.

I am also wondering what happens when I call query function above? After query with that function we also need to use `result_set.next_response()` function to get elements. In the first function do only the offsets of the items on disk are determined and than with `next_response` function they are being retrieved from disk?

Answer (score 0):

[Migrate to DynamoDB v2](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/migrations/dynamodb_v1_to_v2.html) and use `limit` on the query:

```
t.query(
    hash_key__eq="somename", 
    range_key_condition__lt=1389799297,
    reverse=True,
    limit=1
)
```

Comment: I run my python script with logging in debug mode. When I query in your way, in log file I see all items less then range_key. Does client actually retriving all items less then range_key and filter on client machine or it just because of debug mode that prints all details done on dynamo server?

Comment: @mustafa.yavuz If you turn debug on for boto, you will see what is retrieved from DynamoDB server. But I can tell you now, that it is DynamoDB which is returning items matching the condition.